# Getting coordinates to create geojson

Tags: geojson, tilemill, mapbox

I have a geotiff that I have been working with in tilemill and I would like to select portions (buildings) in the map and create new layers as geojson objects. My issue is I don't know how to get the coordinates to create the objects!

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html#_choropleth

this is a link to what I'm trying to do with states I just need the step where the coordinates are gotten because it doesn't seem to be in this document, they just give a shout to the guy who defined them. If anyone has done something similar to this, please give me a shout!

TO CLARIFY

I am not looking for the coordinates for the 50 states, I am trying to create geojson objects for a FICTIONAL map.

Comment: are you trying to convert the picture of the buildings in your geotiff into vectors (to then be converted to geojson)?

Comment: I am very new to this process. I do think yes though, there are buildings that are part of the geotiff and I would like to get them as geojson objects. If converting them to vectors is the way to go what is the approach?

Comment: If your geotiff is a satellite image, then yes, you'll either have to trace them into a vector dataset / layer (to then convert to geojson)... or some automated process that someone might be able to help you with (ie. image classification)...

Comment: Thank you, what would be a good tool to use for this? I'm only looking for barebones, I don't need the color, edges or anything within the object, just its coordinates

Comment: How many features are you looking to extract / convert?

Comment: just the coordinates so i create a geojson object. That is it

Comment: ...but how many buildings potentially? 10's? 1000's?

Comment: 10's more likely

Comment: I'm starting with 4 to test

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

- You can upload your GeoTiff.
- Draw some objects.
- Export them as GeoJSON or something else.